# Set property within object initialisation before Object.defineProperty

Tags: javascript, defineproperty

I would like to set the property x when I first initialise my object, and then call Object.defineProperty. If I try to first access foo.x the console tells me that "value is not defined".

```
var foo = {x:20};

Object.defineProperty(foo, "x", {
    writeable: true,
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true,
    get: function(){ 
      console.log("Get X value");
      return value;
     },
    set: function(newValue){
      console.log("Set X value");
      value = newValue;
    }
});
console.log(foo.x);  // **Uncaught ReferenceError: value is not defined** 
foo.x = 1;
console.log(foo.x);
foo.x = 10;
console.log(foo.x);
```

Comment: Because `value` in your getter and setter are an undefined variable. Even if you want to "refer to itself" somehow, you'll have to define it. Check out [the examples on MDN about `object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Creating_a_property).

Answer (score 0):

Every property has a 'descriptor'.  If you were to introduce this code below, you will see this...

```
var foo = {x:20};

var des = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(foo,'x');
console.log('foo.x - descriptor =',des);
```

---

The descriptor for `foo.x` looks like this:

```
Object {
    value        : 20,
    writable     : true,
    enumerable   : true,
    configurable : true
}
```

As you can see `configurable`,`enumerable` and `writable` have already been pre-set to `true`, so there is no need to do this in `defineProperty`.

---

Also...  If the descriptor has either `get` or `set` it CAN'T have either `value` or `writable`, and vice-versa, as this will cause an error like this:

```
Object.defineProperty(foo,'y',{
    value   : 5,
    get     : function(){return 10}
});
```

Will give the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Invalid property descriptor. Cannot both specify accessors and a value or writable attribute.
```

"accessors" being `get` & `set`.

---

I understand that you are trying to get/set the value of `foo.x`, but you have not defined anything to `value` yet.  Something like, but NOT:

```
Object.defineProperty(foo, "x", {
    var value = this;
```

---

All-in-all you are going about this the wrong way.  Take a look at this code and see if it helps:

```
var foo = {x:20};

Object.defineProperty(foo,'y',{
    get : function(){
        console.log('Get foo.x');
        return this.x;
    },
    set : function(val){
        console.log('Set foo.x');
        this.x = val;
    }
});

console.log(foo.x);     //  20
console.log(foo.y);     //  get foo.x (20)
foo.y = 10;             //  set foo.x to 10
console.log(foo.x);     //  10
console.log(foo.y);     //  10
```